# MVC Setting ApplicationUser to null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model with a foreign key to the ApplicationUser object like this.

```
public virtual ApplicationUser someUser { get; set; }
```

I want this to be nullable so I can either set a user to it like this:

```
updated.someUser = _db.Users.Where(m => m.UserName == Context.User.Identity.Name).SingleOrDefault();
```

Or remove it like this:

```
updated.someUser = null;
```

The funny thing is if debug and step trough it IS working. If I just run it nothing happends.
If I inspect the object before the line it shows this:

```
[System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ApplicationUser_4AF71C23434370A1A8CFA22D42BB10C234BFFB0D2B04A796CF2893A0618F8D5E] = {System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ApplicationUser_4AF71C23434370A1A8CFA22D42BB10C234BFFB0D2B04A796CF2893A0618F8D5E}
```

And F11 to the the next line it correctly gets set:

```
updated.someUser = null
```

I also see this reflected in the database after it saves the changes.
I changed the method from async Task to void to see if this helped but that didn't change anything. Method is beeing called with SignalR if that matters anything.

What is happening here?

**EDIT ****

The method.
Had alot in one liners but changed it to make it more visible.

```
 public void SomeMethod(ViewModel value)
 {
      var updated = _db.someModel.First<Model>(f => f.Id == value.Id);

      if (value.someBool)
      {
          updated.someUser = _db.Users.Where(m => m.UserName == Context.User.Identity.Name).SingleOrDefault();
          updated.someDate = DateTime.Now;
      }
      else 
      {
          updated.someUser = null;
          updated.someDate = null;
      }

      _db.SaveChanges();

      var returnData = new ViewModel()
      {
          // ....
      }
      Clients.All.someMethod(returnData, Context.ConnectionId);
}
```

The `_db` is coming from this in the same class

```
private ApplicationDbContext _db = new ApplicationDbContext();
```

From `IdentityModels.cs`:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public DbSet<Model> someModel { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Going to need a bit more code around this I'm afraid. Is the object called "updated" attached to the context when you make the change? Where is your context instance created?

Comment: It *is* nullable. All properties that reference a class are nullable. What's not necessarily nullable is the *foreign key*. If the primary key on the related object is an int, then by default, the foreign key will be non-nullable, because an int is non-nullable. However, if you explicitly defined the foreign key as `int?` (nullable) that would be different. However, by default, the primary key for `IdentityUser` is a string, which is also nullable by default. Long and short, you need to provide more information about the problem your experiencing.

Comment: Added the method code and more code from where the ApplicationDbContext is created which is not changed from the MVC template.

Comment: The foreign key is coming from public class IdentityUser<TKey, TLogin, TRole, TClaim> : IUser<TKey>  and I think the ID is some sort of GUID (?) Not sure. From the metadata is defined as public virtual TKey Id { get; set; } But I know its nullable since I can manually edit the DB to set it to NULL or as I mentioned, IT WORKS, if I debug and step through the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply changes in child items you need to fetch them too. Without including sub items in your query EF don't track changes on sub item's FK so your changes don't apply. To overcome this simply include user in your query like this:

```
var updated = _db.someModel.Include(f => f.someUser).First<Model>(f => f.Id == value.Id);
```

Comment: Hmmm doesn't look like it let's me use a lambda expression on the include.  Getting "string path" as hint on the intelisense. And getting the error: "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type" if i try to use the code.

Comment: Did you add `System.Data.Entity` namespace?

Comment: Ah that did it and it worked perfect. So complicated >.< Not even a hint to include it :/

Comment: You may also use `db.Entry(updated).Reference(f => f.someUser).Load();` just after your initial query if you don't want to include it directly.